# MSDB database is in recovery_pending state and I don`t have backup of msdb?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

My SQL Server 2008 Developer edition has got Microsoft SQL Server Error 945 error and it is in Recovery_Pending state . It is asking for the log file to be restore or recover but I don`t have backup of of the msdb database . What should I do now . I am not able to view the list of my databases in object explorer and also sql agent service is not visible.

Please help me out.

Thanks ,

Nitesh Kumar

Comment: Please, provide the error message.

Comment: 2013-01-11 11:40:52.83 spid13s     An error occurred while processing the log for database 'msdb'.  If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an article in BOL for this: [Rebuilding System Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).